# Correct way to use ListValueCount

Tags: coldfusion

I need to count total of `?` in a given string. Here is my code:

```
<cfscript>
    myString="UPDATE personnel SET personnel_id = ?, personnel_name = ?, personnel_nric = ?, personnel_staff_num = ?, personnel_designation = ?, personnel_department = ?, personnel_appointed_start_date = ?, personnel_appointed_end_date = ?, personnel_inspection_date = ?, personnel_org_id = ?, lt_dispose_personnel_type_id = ? WHERE id = 49;"
    writeOutput("The count of ? is: " & ListValueCount(myString,"?",","))
</cfscript>
```

but here is my output : `The count of ? is: 0`. My expected output is `11`. What is the correct way to use `ListValueCount` ? Thanks in advance.

CFfiddle : https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=0dee010d-6bde-4ac9-939b-9867b53f128c/da1fade3-c26b-4703-a0b8-0037eddf6345/ecea7294-fba5-464e-ab2f-b919dd94f650.cfm

Comment: Why are you using `listValueCount`? It looks for matches with each list item, not part of a list item. I think the better way will be to use `len(myString)-len(myStringWithoutQuestionMark)`. [Example](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=6758ec74-2326-4e8c-9b33-8257b0a24f8e/7b15e6e8-8d0a-47c0-9fc0-259cefd25270/44e3116e-9a2b-4117-b3fb-e8ecbdef6583.cfm)

Comment: There is no single function of which I am aware that will accomplish your goal of counting the number of times a certain character occurs in a string.  I would use the functions `right` and `find` inside a loop to accomplish this task.

Comment: I couldn't help notice that this is a SQL string and was wondering what the exact objective is. There might be a better option.

Comment: apparently I understand the function `listValueCount` incorrectly. Thank you for the example @rrk . Also another way from your example : https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=330564d2-dc58-4351-bb99-bf5f32b31627/731ff87d-3d93-40a6-b66d-a7b0e544a8e1/a6655021-e155-49dd-902c-6e24d419c9c8.cfm

Comment: `wondering what the exact objective is..There might be a better option`  I'm curious about that too ...

Comment: I invite @rrk to post his first comment as an answer, even though a `correct` one has already been posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `ListValueCount()` counts instances of a specified value in a list (see [listValueCount at cfdocs](https://cfdocs.org/listvaluecount) ).

Because your delimiter is `","` the list will break down into the following list item values (see here the trimmed values):

```
1. "UPDATE personnel SET personnel_id = ?"
2. "personnel_name = ?"
3. "personnel_nric = ?"
4. "personnel_staff_num = ?"
5. "personnel_designation = ?"
6. "personnel_department = ?"
7. "personnel_appointed_start_date = ?"
8. "personnel_appointed_end_date = ?"
9. "personnel_inspection_date = ?"
10. "personnel_org_id = ?"
11. "lt_dispose_personnel_type_id = ? WHERE id = 49;"
```

Because you are looking for the specific item value `"?"`, no item can be found: Each of the string values above consist of more than one question mark!

**Solution 1:** Use a regular expression search, e.g.,

```
<cfscript>
    myString="UPDATE personnel SET personnel_id = ? , personnel_name = ?  , personnel_nric = ?, personnel_staff_num = ?, personnel_designation = ?, personnel_department = ?, personnel_appointed_start_date = ?, personnel_appointed_end_date = ?, personnel_inspection_date = ?, personnel_org_id = ?, lt_dispose_personnel_type_id = ? WHERE id = 49;"
    writeOutput("The count of ? is: " & reFind("\?.+?,?", myString,1,true,"ALL").len())
</cfscript>
```

**Solution 2:** If you are using a more modern cfml engine, another possibility is to loop your list with a [listReduce()](https://cfdocs.org/listreduce) member function like so:

```
<cfscript>
myString="UPDATE personnel SET personnel_id = ?, personnel_name = ?, personnel_nric = ?, personnel_staff_num = ?, personnel_designation = ?, personnel_department = ?, personnel_appointed_start_date = ?, personnel_appointed_end_date = ?, personnel_inspection_date = ?, personnel_org_id = ?, lt_dispose_personnel_type_id = ? WHERE id = 49;"
writeOutput("The count of ? is: " & myString.listReduce( 
    ( acc, element ) => {
        if( findNoCase( "?", element ) ){
            return acc+1;
        }else{
            return acc;
        }

    }

    , 0, ","
    ));</cfscript>
```

**Solution 3** would be the classic way using [cfloop](https://cfdocs.org/cfloop) and loop through each item and do findNoCase similar to the listReduce function above.

**Side note:** I suppose you are doing some kind of  dynamic SQL query or debugging. Please be carefull creating those, especially when creating dynamic SQL queries. The regex solution 1 may have side effects according to the content of the list you are creating. You need to test it carefully!

Comment: thank you for the assistance. I appreciate your code example.

Comment: Fyi, the regex misses 1 item if the `?` is the last character in the string.

Comment: @SOS: you are correct. That's exactly what I've mentioned in the side note in the last sentence about side effects when changing the SQL string. For that specific variation you'd need to use the RegEx  "\?.+?[,;]?".

Comment: True, nothing is foolproof. Though a simple `?` search is probably better for quick and dirty sql parameter parsing, since it would also work with other statement types, such as statements using `AND Col = ? `.  Again, not bullet proof, but does support more scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Why `ListValueCount` is not the right tool for what you are trying to implement, is already well explained by @andreasRu.

There is one more alternative(in comments) to the answers provided by @andreasRu, which the following. I feel this is the simplest solution.

```
myString="UPDATE personnel SET personnel_id = ?, personnel_name = ?, personnel_nric = ?, personnel_staff_num = ?, personnel_designation = ?, personnel_department = ?, personnel_appointed_start_date = ?, personnel_appointed_end_date = ?, personnel_inspection_date = ?, personnel_org_id = ?, lt_dispose_personnel_type_id = ? WHERE id = 49;"
writeOutput("The count of ? is: " & Len(myString) - Len(Replace(myString, '?', '', 'all')))
```

We are simply checking the length difference between the initial string and the string after all `?` are stripped from it.